# Enero lo toma como mes 0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Buen día, tengo una consulta. Estoy automatizando en java y mi aplicativo me esta tomando el mes enero como 0 y al aplicativo me arroja que tiene que ser superior al mes correspondiente. Este es el string que utilizo. Es un public static String obtenerFechaHoy.

````
        Calendar fechahoy = new GregorianCalendar();
        int año = fechahoy.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes = fechahoy.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia = fechahoy.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println("Valor día = " + dia);
        System.out.println("Valor mes = " + mes);
        System.out.println("Valor año = " + año);
        return  (  dia + "/" + (mes+1) + "/" + año);```
````

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: `int mes = fechahoy.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es importante tener en cuenta un detalle. Para Calendar los meses van de 0 a 11, es decir, 0 es Enero y 11 es Diciembre.

Fuente:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

```
int enero=Calendar.JANUARY;//0
int febrero=Calendar.FEBRUARY;//1
```